# Java Spring properties inject @Value instance Null

Tags: java, spring

I have a class to load the properties, but when I create an instance the class is always null.

```
import lombok.Getter;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
public class Blacklist
{
 @Getter
 @Value("${blacklist.regex:}")
 public String regex;
}
```

Instance

```
public class Filter{

  private BlackList blacklist = new BlackList();

  private regex = blackList.getRegex();

 }
```

Blacklist is null

I tryed with @autowired but it didn't works.
Properties:

```
blacklist.regex=^.{1,50}$
```

Comment: Share the section of your properties file where `blacklist.regex` is defined

Comment: Are you sure you are running the code in a Spring context? Spring normally reacts with an exception if a property cannot be resolved. Also, I am not sure your empty default value (no value after colon in @Value expression) would work.

Comment: `new BlackList()` won't work in any case. That instance of `Blacklist` is not know to Spring and it won't do anything with or about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think here are multiple problems.

1. You try to define a bean with a @Configuration annotation (Can technically work but bad practice)
2. You create your instance Blacklist manually without spring context
3. (May be wrong, just a design thing) You use value injection in a model object.
4. Typo in your @Value value

My recommendations:

- You should inject the value in a service (@Service/@Component) as field
- Try removing the : in your @Value annotation
- The class consuming/creating the instance should also be in a spring context

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem, my class Filter doesn't have Spring logic to inject the values I will use the Bean configurator and constructor.

```
@Value("${blacklist.regex:}")
public String regex;

 @Bean
 public Filter()
 {
   return new Filter(regex);
 }
```